# Getting all the textField value from tableView into Array and Validation

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have two tableView with similar cell design. there is two textField inside the cell call Name & Age. You can see in the image.[image]

Now user fill there data into each textField. then On `continue` button I want to append all the name in on array. Similar for the Age.

And also want to put the validation for the blank value. If any textfield is blank the on `Continue` button the alert is popUp.

Comment: Why do you have two tableviews? Use one tableview and two sections

Answer (score 1):

You could get the cell of the tableview by using method [cellForRow(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow), and then access the name label or age label accordingly like below,

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
if let cell = yourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? yourTableViewCell {
    let name = cell.nameLabel.text
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in `ViewController` and implement `TextFieldEndEditing` method and in that save the edited textfield text in array of string.

Please refer below link to get all the textfield values.

https://phrkrish.wordpress.com/2016/12/25/table-view-with-text-field-in-swift-3-0/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two tableviews use one tableview with two sections. And don't use dequeueReusableCell. Create two arrays of your UITableViewCell objects. And get the textfield value from the array objects in continue button action.

//CustomCell.swift

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    let titleLbl = UILabel()
    let seatNoLbl = UILabel()
    let nameTxtField = UITextField()
    let ageTxtField = UITextField()
    //etc
}
```

//ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let tableView = UITableView()
    var onwardSeatNos = ["L1","L15"]
    var returnSeatNos = ["L2","L3"]
    var onwardSeatCells = [CustomCell]()
    var returnSeatCells = [CustomCell]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        onwardSeatNos.enumerated().forEach { (index,seatNo) in
            let cell = CustomCell()
            print(index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index))
            cell.titleLbl.text = index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index)
            cell.seatNoLbl.text = "Seat No. \(seatNo)"
            onwardSeatCells.append(cell)
        }
        returnSeatNos.enumerated().forEach { (index,seatNo) in
            let cell = CustomCell()
            cell.titleLbl.text = index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index)
            cell.seatNoLbl.text = "Seat No. \(seatNo)"
            returnSeatCells.append(cell)
        }
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return returnSeatNos.isEmpty ? 1 : 2
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return onwardSeatNos.count
        } else {
            return returnSeatNos.count
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return onwardSeatCells[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            return returnSeatCells[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 0 {
            return "Passenger Information (Onward)"
        } else {
            return "Passenger Information (Return)"
        }
    }
    @objc func confirmBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let index = onwardSeatCells.firstIndex(where: { $0.nameTxtField.text!.isEmpty }) {
            print("Onward " + (index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index)) + " name is empty")
        } else if let index = onwardSeatCells.firstIndex(where: { $0.nameTxtField.text!.isEmpty }) {
            print("Onward " + (index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index)) + " age is empty")
        } else if let index = returnSeatCells.firstIndex(where: { $0.nameTxtField.text!.isEmpty }) {
            print("Return " + (index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index)) + " name is empty")
        } else if let index = returnSeatCells.firstIndex(where: { $0.nameTxtField.text!.isEmpty }) {
            print("Return " + (index == 0 ? "Primary Passenger" : String(format: "Co-passenger %02d", index)) + " age is empty")
        } else {
            let onwardNamesArr = onwardSeatCells.map { $0.nameTxtField.text! }
            let onwardAgesArr = onwardSeatCells.map { $0.ageTxtField.text! }
            let returnNamesArr = returnSeatCells.map { $0.nameTxtField.text! }
            let returnAgesArr = returnSeatCells.map { $0.ageTxtField.text! }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func getAllTextFieldText(tableView: UITableView) {
    for i in 0...6 { // Depending on how many fields you need
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? yourCell {
            if let values = cell.textField.text {
                // *values* are all the text from each textField
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Continuing with @Michael Wang answer, for multiple textfields you can simply run a for loop to get all the values you need and add them to an array or whatever you want.I hope this helps anyone else in the future.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding `0...6`, you can use the row/section count of the table view.